# Ensure App Closes when Back Button Press Android

Tags: android, audio, webview, android-webview

I have an app that opens a web view and uses a javascript interface to play audio on my Android App. I want the app to close if you hit the back button, which should be happening automatically, but it's not.

The only 2 activities I have are the MainActivity and the WebAppInterface. It's possible that the back button is closing the main activity, but the WebAppInterface for the web view (that also plays the audio) isn't closing when the back button is pressed, but I'm not sure.

Any advice? I would post the code, but there's nothing to see here. A note, I never call

```
finish();
```

anywhere in the app, and maybe I should?

Answer (score 2):

> I want the app to close if you hit the back button

What your users want is for the music to stop when the user hits the back button. Presumably, you will do that by the same sort of mechanism that you used to start the music in the first place.

> A note, I never call finish(); anywhere in the app, and maybe I should?

This happens automatically when the BACK button is pressed, assuming you have not done anything to interfere with it (e.g., overrode `onBackPressed()` and failed to chain to the superclass).

Comment: So right now I'm trying to use onBackPressed() to stop the audio if it's playing. Should I not do that? I'm not sure what you're suggesting, but I agree: i want the music to stop if the back button is pressed. They only way I can think of to do that is call onBackPressed() is that wrong?

Comment: @TommyNicholas: "So right now I'm trying to use onBackPressed() to stop the audio if it's playing. Should I not do that?" -- no, that is fine, other than whatever you are doing in your `onBackPressed()` implementation to stop the audio apparently is not working, based on your question. "They only way I can think of to do that is call onBackPressed() is that wrong?" -- you never **call** `onBackPressed()`. `onBackPressed()` is **called** by the framework when the user presses BACK.

Comment: ok. Shit. So I've put 

public void onBackPressed(){ 
   mp.release();
  }

Inside my WebAppInterface, and it doesn't seem to be firing.

Comment: @TommyNicholas: Though it is more likely that you want to do something else, such as stop the music in `onStop()`, to handle other scenarios as well that cause your application to leave the foreground (e.g., incoming phone call).

Comment: OH onStop() - yes that's what I want, whenever the app stops I need to destroy/release the player. Do I need to override on stop or does that just get called whenever it stops?

Comment: @TommyNicholas: `onStop()` is called when your activity is no longer visible, because something else has completely taken over the foreground.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39216/discussion-between-tommy-nicholas-and-commonsware)

Comment: @TommyNicholas You should understand the relationship between "super" classes, super methods and overrides.  Basic Java stuff.

Comment: I'm so bad at Java, but I worked on it a bit today and got it working. Won't post a solution, because I didn't really solve the issue I originally proposed.

Answer (score 0):

You can can call finish when you start the WebAppInterface from MainActivity.
Like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, WebAppInterface.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

This way when you call finish on the WebAppInterface, it won't go back to the MainActivity instead it will close like the MainActivity does.

Comment: I'm not sure that's what I want - I don't call finish() ever, I just want the WebAppInterface to end whenever the MainActivity does, not when I call finish() directly. Would that still happen with this code?

Comment: Yup, it should still work. Calling finish in the MainActivity after starting a new activity removes the MainActivity from the stack. I normally use this method for SplashScreens. The back button should not go back to the MainActivity after that!